# Retrieving the Property from the Kind using Entity class in google cloud data store?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-datastore

Can any one explain, how can I fetch the property of individual row in google datastore, this is my code

```
public Entity useravailable(String name, String pass) {
    DatastoreService entityStore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Key k = KeyFactory.createKey("databasecont", name);
    try {
      Entity user = entityStore.get(k);
      System.out.println("password of user in db"+userHaveAccount);
      if ("password".equals(password)) // Here check the database password with the password("passed as argument to this function")
          return userHaveAccount;
      else
          return null;
    } 
    catch (EntityNotFoundException e1) {
      return null;
    }
}
```

in if condition I need to check the value get from the database(password) with the argument passed(pass), how can retrieve the password from the database?

Kind(table name) -> databasecont,

properities(columns)  -> name, password,

key(primary key) -> name

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like -

```
String password = (String) entity.getProperty("password"); 

//The above assumes that the name of the property in the Datastore is "password".
```

You can refer to the API Documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity).

Comment: Thank you, It is working. I tried with `Map<String, Object> map = userHaveAccount.getProperties();
   String dbvalue = (String) map.get("password");` , this is used to retrieve all the property. Once again Thanks for you response, It is too useful for me